# discriminator column is not working with table per subclass

Tags: hibernate

[image: JARS used]Hi All,

I am using discriminator column in table per subclass inheritence mapping. This is the entry of parent class

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "employee105")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)   
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="emp_type" , discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING)
```

and entries of subclass are as follows:

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="contractemployee105")
@DiscriminatorValue("P")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID") 

@Entity  
@Table(name="regularemployee105")
@DiscriminatorValue("T")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID")
```

I know my code is correct and tables are being generated but in insert query discriminator column is not being created. I am using jars as shown in image. kindly let me know the issue. I suspect that this is the issue with JARS or hibernate version. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely as you suspect a problem with your hibernate version.  Bug [HHH-6911](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6911) was exactly this issue, and was resolved in Hibernate 4.2.9, 4.3.1.  If your version of hibernate is earlier, you might want to upgrade.  (Looking at your list of jars, this indeed appears to be the case.)

As noted in Stefan's answer, Hibernate doesn't need the discriminator in this case, but the JPA spec says it should be allowed and persisted if specified.

Answer (score 1):

With table per subclass, you don't need a discriminator. Hibernate determines the subclass by finding a record in the relevant table.

Comment: thanks for the reply stefan but I am facing the problem while fetching the object. Employee emp  = (Employee)session.load(Employee.class, 2); plz tell me how to get the object which belongs to one of the subclass and i dnt know the id is of which type of employee.

Comment: @rishi - do you mean your load is failing or that you don't know which type you have after the load?  If it's the latter, you might just need an instanceof check.